# Trying to properly print an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, int

I am new to Programming so bear with me if I do not properly present my issue.  I have an assignment to create a program to assign integer values 1-25 to a 25 element integer array.  I need to print the array as five separate lines with each line containing 5 elements separated by commas.  The last element does not have a comma following it.  The final output should be as follows:

> 1,2,3,4,5
>
> 6,7,8,9,10
>
> 11,12,13,14,15
>
> 16,17,18,19,20
>
> 21,22,23,24,25

The code that I came up with comes close, but it's not quite right.  The code that I came up with is:

```
public class Test2 {

/**
 * @param args
 *            the command line arguments
 */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] numbers = new int[25];
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            numbers[i] = i + 1;

            System.out.print(numbers[i] + ",");
            if (i % 5 == 0 && i > 0)
                System.out.println();

        }
    }
}
```

The printout that I get from my code is as follows:

> 1,2,3,4,5,6,
>
> 7,8,9,10,11,
>
> 12,13,14,15,16,
>
> 17,18,19,20,21,
>
> 22,23,24,25,

I am not sure why I am getting 1-6 on the first line as well as how to remove the comma at the end of each line.  Any help pointing out my errors would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is that you are checking if int i is divisible by 5 (i % 5), not numbers[i] (numbers[i] % 5). This way, your code prints:

```
number 1 when i = 0,
number 2 when i = 1,
number 3 when i = 2,
number 4 when i = 3,
number 5 when i = 4,
number 6 when i = 5
```

and finally prints line break.

The correct code is:

```
int[] numbers = new int[25];
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    numbers[i]=i+1;

    System.out.print(numbers[i]);
    if (numbers[i] % 5 == 0 && i > 0) {
        System.out.println();
    } else {
        System.out.print(",");
    }
}
```

The above code will print (as intended):

```
1,2,3,4,5
6,7,8,9,10
11,12,13,14,15
16,17,18,19,20
21,22,23,24,25
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting 6 numbers on the first line, because you start counting at `i=0`, and only print the newline once `i=5`; at which point the number you've just printed is 6, not 5 - you're printing `i+1` in each iteration.

If you made your logic such that it printed EITHER a comma OR a newline but not both, you'd get rid of the commas at the ends of the lines.

Comment: Thank you for replying.  I knew it was something simple that I was missing.

Answer (score 1):

You're close.  ***Very*** close.

Consider what your condition is checking - you want to inspect a value `i`, and want to stop when that particular value is divisible by 5 but is nonzero.

The problem is that you have the wrong value - `i` isn't what you want, but `numbers[i]`.  The reason:  each number in `numbers[i]` is offset of `i` by 1.

What you want to do is check if `numbers[i]` is divisible by 5. You still need to check for a nonzero `i`, though.

```
if(numbers[i] % 5 == 0 && i > 0) {
    System.out.println(numbers[i]);
} else {
    System.out.print(numbers[i] + ",");
}
```

Comment: Don't need to check `i > 0` any more.

Comment: Thank you both for replying.  You found my error.  Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
if (i % 5 == 0 && i > 0)
```

with

```
if (i % 5 == 4)
```

Comment: Thanks for replying to my question.  It is appreciated.